# get return Value null in method in android

Tags: android

I write one function for get data from database.

I have set a breakpoint and make sure the function is already get data for return

but when I use the function I Can't get data back in My main function

is my data structure error? or other thing error?

thanks for your help.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ScheduleData {

public String strID;
public String strName;
public String strDesc;
public Integer iScheduleDay;
public String strStartDate;
public ArrayList<ScheduleContent> alPOI;

public ScheduleData() {
    strID = new String();
    strName = new String();
    strDesc = new String();
    strStartDate = new String();
    iScheduleDay = 0;
    alPOI = new ArrayList<ScheduleContent>();       
}
}
```

//

```
public class ScheduleContent {

public String strPOIID;
public int iSequence ;
public int iDay ;
public String strTime;
public int iStayTime ;

public ScheduleContent() {

    iSequence = 1;
    iDay = 1;
    iStayTime = 0;
}

}
```

//

```
public boolean bInitData() {

ArrayList<ScheduleData> alEx = alGetAllSchedule();

}

private ArrayList<ScheduleData> alGetAllSchedule() {
    ArrayList<ScheduleData> alTmp = new ArrayList<ScheduleData>();
    try {
        mDATA.m_alAllSchedule.clear();
        Cursor c = objSchedule.getAllCursor();
        ScheduleDataInit();

        if (c.getCount() > 0) {
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                while (c.isAfterLast() == false) {
                    ScheduleData sTmp = new ScheduleData();
                    sTmp.strID = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("SID"));
                    sTmp.strName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("S_Name"));

                    sTmp.strDesc = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("S_Desc"));
                    sTmp.strStartDate = c.getString(c
                            .getColumnIndex("S_StartDate"));

                    sTmp.iScheduleDay = Integer.valueOf(c.getInt(c
                            .getColumnIndex("S_Day")));

                    sTmp.alPOI=mDATA.m_hAllScheduleContent.get(sTmp.strID);


                    alTmp.add(sTmp);
                    c.moveToNext();
                }
            }

        }
        mDATA.m_alAllSchedule = alTmp;
        c.close();
    } catch (Exception errMsg) {
        errMsg.printStackTrace();
    }
    return alTmp;
}
```

Comment: Please mention which method are you calling to get data and how are you calling. show the Activity flow.

Comment: in OnCreate , I will initialize Data for Activity to show.
so I call bInitData() to do it(like example),but I don't Know why bInitData() can't get the data back from alGetAllSchedule()?